# How would I decode a string that was coded by this program?

Tags: python

This is the code I used to code it

```
import string 

def encode(text,rotate_by):
    s_from = string.ascii_lowercase + string.ascii_uppercase
    s_to = (string.ascii_lowercase[rotate_by:] +
            string.ascii_lowercase[:rotate_by] + 
            string.ascii_uppercase[rotate_by:] + 
            string.ascii_uppercase[:rotate_by])
    cypher_table = string.maketrans(s_from, s_to)
    cypher_table = string.maketrans(s_from, s_to)
    return text.translate(cypher_table)


text = raw_input("Enter the text to encode: ")
rotate_by = int(raw_input("Rotate by: "))
print encode(text, rotate_by)
```

How would I decode a string coded by this?

Comment: just reverse the logic

Answer (score 0):

This is a very simple rotation encoding. You just have to reverse the rotation.

I would try this:

```
def decode(text, rotate_by):
    s_from = string.ascii_lowercase + string.ascii_uppercase
    s_to = (string.ascii_lowercase[rotate_by:] +
        string.ascii_lowercase[:rotate_by] + 
        string.ascii_uppercase[rotate_by:] + 
        string.ascii_uppercase[:rotate_by])
    reverse_table = string.maketrans(s_to, s_from)
    return text.translate(reverse_table)
```

BTW: In your coding, the string.maketrans-line is duplicative.

The important line above is the maketrans-line, because I just reversed the parameters, this should also reverse the translation table. Everything else is similar or equal than the original code.

Answer (score 0):

Just call encode with the encoded(encrypted) string and the original rotate_by with its sign inversed.

Ex:

```
>>> encode("hello",3)
'khoor'
>>> encode("khoor",-3)
'hello'
```